# control+c signal in qemu

Tags: linux, qemu, sigint, mips64

Can anyone please help me to understand how qemu handle control+c signal? And in which file? (or some useful links to understand it)
I want to make route (like call graph). Actually this signal is not working on my mips guest (but working on malta mips with same host)
Thank You,

host & guest OS: Linux
Guest architecture: Mips64
Host architecture: x86
QEMU Version: qemu-1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same problem `https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1089005` here,

If u want to kill qemu ,if ctrl+c doesnt work then use `kill -9 pid`

Comment: i updated them on this bug that the issue is still there on QEMU version 2.9.50